# How to disable showing cluster counts? (Gmaps4Rails)

Tags: gmaps4rails

I am using [Google Maps for Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) and though I like the clusterer, I do not want to display cluster sizes. Is there a way to disable marker text without modifying the clusterer's source code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this without modifying the source code. [Open the source code](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js) and search for `innerHTML` and then look a few lines lower, at the following line, which is clearly not capable of alternative behaviour:

```
"'>" + this.sums_.text + "</div>";
```

[Apparently some folks found this codebase's source control system (SVN) inadequate](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/issues/9#issuecomment-55144994), and they [forked it to GitHub](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus). Later they added capability, including [the ability to hide the label via the following method](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/blob/736b0e3a7d916fbeb2ee5007494f17a5329b11a8/src/markerclusterer.js#L1094):

```
setHideLabel(true)
```

With Google Maps for Rails, do the following:

```
handler.clusterer.serviceObject.setHideLabel(true);
```